# How to access "this" from within an anonymous function within Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to fire an event after a few seconds, so i have decided to go with Javascript's setInterval method. This is happening inside one of my methods attached to the Vue instance. The problem i'm facing is that I can't update the model from the setInterval method. The following is my code:

```
new Vue({
      el: 'body',
      data: {
        feedback: '',
      },
      methods: {
        giveFeedback: function () {
          setTimeout(function(){
            this.feedback = "changed";
          }, 3000);
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: Short answer is either use arrow functions in your set timeout function or do var self = this before the set timeout and use self.feedback instead of this.feedback